# Orbits and stabilisers of $D_{8}$ on set of 2-subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$

Tags: group-theory, group-actions, dihedral-groups

(Might get some things wrong, just started)

Let the group be dihedral group $D_8$ and the set be set of $2$-subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$, which is $\{\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,4\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,4\}, \{3,4\}\}$.

How would I go about getting the ${\rm orb}_{D_8}(\{1,2\})$, because I just used vertices of a square and got $\{\{4,1\}, \{3,4\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2\}, \{4,3\}, \{2,1\}, \{1,4\}, \{3,2\}\}$, but orbits should partition the set, and orbit of the first element already has more elements than the set itself.

> Does $\{1,4\}$ and $\{4,1\}$ count as the same element? Or am I doing something else wrong here?

Just a whole lot of confusion . . .

Comment: On top of the confusion about ordering of elements in a set, there is another problem. $D_8$ is not transitive on $2$-subsets, so you shouldn't be getting all these in the orbit. It's not possible to give the correct answer, because it depends on how you are labelling your square. But think about this: in a square, we can take a set of two adjacent vertices, and also a set of two non-adjacent vertices. Are these two set in the same orbit of $D_8$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does $\{1,4\}$ and $\{4,1\}$ count as the same element?

Yes.

They are the same set.

For any set $S=\{ a, b\}$, we have, by definition of a set, that $S=\{ b, a\}$.

More generally, a set $\mathcal{S}$ is considered equal to any set $\mathcal{T}$ whose elements are a permutation of the elements of $\mathcal{S}$ and there are no other and no fewer elements in $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: but group theory talks about permutation of a set and stuff, wouldnt this make all actions in a dihedral group an identity? or any action of any group for that matter.

Comment: There is an underlying assumption that such a set is ordered, in order for there to be a permutation. In general, sets have no order, @5Six. Here we are talking about $2$-subsets of $\overline{1,4}$, which are themselves sets.